# Removing a row from grid without deleting it in the database

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm trying to remove rows in the grid extjs 3.4 which have status= F. Any idea on how to do so?

```
var status = null;
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "",
           dataType : 'xml',
           data : {
            "Where" : "Status='F'"
           },
         success:function(xml) {
             $(xml).find('record').each(function () {
                status = $(this).find("PK").text();
             });
             if(status) {


             }
         },
         error: function (error) {
             alert('error');
         }
       });
```

Comment: By adding some more filter rule? Filter the id (or primary key)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Michel Franke, add a Filter but with a function to exclude the status `store.filterBy(function(record){
      return record.get('status') != 'F';
 }`